# HDF5 chunking without compression leads to increase in file size

Tags: compression, hdf5, chunking

I have an unchunked, uncompressed HDF5 file with a size of 460MB. I use h5repack to save the file with compressed chunks like this:

```
h5repack -v -l CHUNK=128x128x1 -f GZIP=1 file.h5 file_chunked.h5
```

This works great and the resulting file size is about 1/3 of the original  (170MB).

However, if I try to use **chunking without compression** like this

```
h5repack -v -l CHUNK=128x128x1 -f NONE file.h5 file_chunked.h5
```

or even

```
h5repack -v -l CHUNK=128x128x1 file.h5 file_chunked.h5
```

then the resulting file size is *dramatically larger* (10x) than the original (3.9GB).

The resulting datasets' dimensions, datatypes, and content seems to be the same. When I examine the file in HDFView, I can see no difference to the original one other than Chunking being set to 128x128x1.

I would expect the chunked but uncompressed file to be roughly the same size as the original.

Can someone explain this to me? I'm probably missing something fundamental here.

Loads of thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each chunk carries some overhead. Internally they are nodes in a B-tree. This overhead is multiplied by the number of chunks. If you have relatively small chunks, you will have a lot of them. Without compression, this overhead can be huge.

The page about [things that can affect performance](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/perfissues.html) says:

> Avoid using a chunk size that is really small. There can be a lot of overhead with a small chunk size, which can affect performance, in addition to making the file a lot larger.

Comment: Thanks Simon,
I had read these instructions before and I was certain I had chosen a reasonable chunk size for my datasets. They are rather large in x and y (5,000) and very small in z (15).

But I found out now that I had the order of dimensions mixed up. It has to be 1x128x128 (z first) instead of 128x128x1 which obviously makes a huge difference.

Comment: Great! I was surprised by the amount of overhead. That explains it nicely!